# Not able to match new line in between closing and opening tag

Tags: php, regex

I am having following tags, I want to replace class name of p tag which follows h2 tag.

```
    <h2>H2 Tag</h2>
    
    <p class="cn">But you forget</p>
```

I have tried the following

```
/* </h2>(.*)<p class="cn"> */

preg_match('/<\/h2>(.*)<p class="cn">/m', $input_line, $output_array);
```

It's not matching new line

Comment: Replace `/m` (that makes no sense in the pattern) with `/s` to make `.` match line break chars (that it does not match by default).

Comment: The regular expressions are a powerful tool but not powerful enough to parse HTML.

Comment: Use a proper parser. On php backend, [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/) does it pretty nicely. On frontend, [JS does it perfectly](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)